# How to get current feature file name running in java8 and older dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, pom.xml, bdd

How to get current feature file name running in java using DriverFactory class or runner file for older dependencies version and java 8?

I tried using Feature Scenario but it didn't work for me. Is there any way we can fetch the current name of feature file or maybe tags dynamically while running?

Answer (score 1):

To get the name of the currently executing feature file in a Cucumber-Java test, one common approach is to use a `Before` hook and extract details from the `Scenario` object that's provided to the hook method.

The example below demonstrates how you can get the feature file name and tags:

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
    import cucumber.api.java.Before;
    
    public class Hooks {
    
        @Before
        public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {
            String featureName = "Feature ";
            String rawFeatureName = scenario.getId().split(";")[0].replace("-"," ");
            featureName = featureName + rawFeatureName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + rawFeatureName.substring(1);
            
            // print the feature name
            System.out.println("Feature Name: " + featureName);
    
            // print scenario's tags
            for (String tag : scenario.getSourceTagNames()) {
                System.out.println("Tag: " + tag);
            }
        }
    }
```

A few notes:

- scenario.getId() returns a string that contains the feature file's path and name. Splitting this string by ";" gives an array, where the first element is a "slugified" version of the feature name.
  We then manipulate the slugified feature name to transform it back into a more readable feature name.
- scenario.getSourceTagNames() returns a set of tags for the scenario.
  This approach works for many older versions of Cucumber, especially if you're on Java 8. But remember that the exact methods available and their behaviors can vary depending on the specific version of the Cucumber library you are using.

Comment: @KrittikaAgrawal would you please consider it as accepted answer. thanks